# using include in named.conf returns file not found although the file does exist

Tags: linux, bind, named-conf

I have a named service running fine but when I try to use an additional "include" statement, it doesn't work.

I'm using Linux Server, and I have the same problem in CentOS and AlmaLinux.

I have a simple "include" statement in my named.conf:

```
include "/var/named/chroot/etc/secondary.conf";
```

and when I start named it returns the error

```
/etc/named.conf:39: open: /var/named/chroot/etc/secondary.conf: file not found
```

The file exists.

I've tried to change the location of the file, permissions, name, etc. but it continues answering the same error.

Any ideas about where the problem is? I would appreciate some kind of help.

The configuration is simple but it only fails when I introduce the last include, here you can read it:

```
options 
      { allow-recursion { 
                 localnets; 
       }; 
       include "/etc/named-user-options.conf"; 
       directory "/var"; 
       pid-file "/var/run/named/named.pid"; 
};

controls { 
           inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 
            allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; }; 
};

zone "." { 
          type hint; 
          file "named.root"; 
};

zone "0.0.127.IN-ADDR.ARPA" { 
        type master; 
        file "localhost.rev"; 
};

include "/var/named/chroot/etc/secondary.conf";
```

Comment: Remember that Linux is case sensitive - if your file is named `Secondary.conf` that's not the same as if it is named `secondary.conf`. That tripped me up a few times back in the day.

Comment: Thanks @tsc_chazz, yes, I know it and is correctly written, ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are running under chroot, then you need to drop part which references that.

bind9 reads the command line switches, executes `chroot`, then reads the config files.

You therefore need to drop the part which references the chroot path, so try `/etc/secondary.conf`.

If you are also running some Linux kernel security module, then you will need to modify those setting to ensure that the path can be read.

Comment: Many thanks Bib!
I just moved the file to /etc/secondary.conf and it woks perfectly.
Thank you for your help after wasting so much time.

Comment: @David. in that case, please mark it as the answer to help others.

Comment: I tried the same day you answered the post but the portal doesn't allow me to do it, it requires a minimum reputation to do it and I'm a rookie here :(